# How to edit the hello world driver for Minix/ARM running on a BeagleBone Black

Tags: operating-system, arm, driver, beagleboneblack, minix

I am a novice student in operating systems, and am having some trouble with a seemingly trivial task. I am simply trying to edit the hello world driver on Minix/ARM running on a BeagleBone Black to print something different from the original message. My first issue is that I cannot think of a way to clone the Minix source-tree onto the board. Git is not installed, nor is there a package manager for Minix/ARM yet, I have tried the method from Thomas Cort's [blog post](http://minix-i2c.blogspot.ca/2013/06/transfering-files-over-serial-to.html) on how to transfer files over serial, but it is a bit finicky.

So, my first question is: how should I go about cloning the source-tree into Minix?

Second, it is unclear to me what the best workflow is for driver development within Minix. I have read nearly all of the tutorials on the Minix website (such as [programming device drivers](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:driverprogramming)), but it is still unclear to me just how I should go about editing/adding device drivers. I have tried creating entirely new files for the hello world driver exactly as the page linked above specifies, but I get the following error code:

```
dhcp-10-76-30-133.union.edu#  make MAKEVERBOSE=3
echo '#  ' "compile " hello2/hello2.o
#   compile  hello2/hello2.o
false -O2 -fno-builtin -msoft-float -Werror     -D_MINIX_SYSTEM=1  -c          hello2.c
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/hello2
dhcp-10-76-30-133.union.edu#
```

How should I go about editing/compiling these files?

Thank you in advance for your time and patience!

Comment: `false` is not a compiler...

Comment: I haven never worked in Minix so i am just suggesting it from outsider perspective. are you trying to compile driver on Beaglebone black running Minix ? Isn't cross compilation of driver in PC and transferring it to BBB over serial is easy. I know you don't like to transfer files over serial but if your files are not big why not follow it ?

Comment: The rationale in the serial article seems to be "save having to physically move an SD card between machines to transfer a tiny amount of data", which implies that physically moving an SD card between machines is a) still an option, and b) probably the appropriate one for non-tiny amounts of data...